# NumberFormatter strange behavior in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

i'm trying to add spacing to a number on input, but after 1000 the formatter resets the value

```
amountTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldFilter(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

```
@objc private func textFieldFilter(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else {return}
        print("String text\(text)")
        print("Integer text\(Int(text))")
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        formatter.groupingSize = 3
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        textField.text = formatter.string(for: Int(text))
    }
```

In console prints this:

```
String text 1
Integer text Optional(1)
String text 10
Integer text Optional(10)
String text 100
Integer text Optional(100)
String text 1000
Integer text Optional(1000)
String text 1 0000
Integer text nil
```

Comment: `Int(text)` of "1 000"  is nil, but `Int(1000)` is "1000", it's because of the space. The `Int` constructor will fails if you have for instance `" 1000"`, or in your case `1 000`, as soon as there is an invalid character (a space).

Comment: how can i solve this problem then?

Comment: You could remove all spaces before calling `Int(text.replacingOccurences(of: " ", with "")`, but there might be a cleaner solution

Comment: Why are you setting a specific group separator and grouping size? Users of your app in other countries are not going to be happy with the strange (to them) number formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialiser `Int(_ text: String)?` does not use your formatter to parse the text you pass to it. Hence `"1 0000"` is not parsed as a valid number and `Int("1 0000")` returns `nil`. It also doesn't help that, in the last case, your group size is 4, not 3.

Here is some code that works

```
let text = "1 000"
print("String text \(text)")
print("Integer text \(Int(text) ?? -1)") // ?? -1 silences the warning for a nil result
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSize = 3
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
if let number = formatter.number(from: text)
{
    print("number \(number)")
    let numberAsString = formatter.string(from: number)
    print("number as string '\(numberAsString ?? "nil")'")
    let numberAsInt = Int(truncating: number)
    print("numberAsInt \(numberAsInt)")
    let numberAsIntAsString = formatter.string(from: numberAsInt as NSNumber)
    print("numberAsIntAsString '\(numberAsIntAsString ?? "nil")'")

}
```

prints

```
String text 1 000
Integer text -1
number 1000
number as string '1 000'
numberAsInt 1000
numberAsIntAsString '1 000'
```

The first line is the text (which I assign directly and you get from the field.

The second line is the result of `Int(text)` which is -1 because `Int(text)` is `nil` but I use `??` to assign a default.

The third line is the result of using the formatter to get an `NSNumber` from the field

The fourth line is the result of feeding that number back into the formatter.

The fifth line prints the `NSNumber` converted to an `Int`

The last line prints the `Int` converted back to an `NSNumber` and then back to a string with the formatter.